# Trim of string doesn't display in IE prior to 9

Tags: javascript, string, internet-explorer-8, trim

```
   {{if inventory.title.length > 38}}
            <p class="p1">
                {{>(inventory.title.substring(0, 38) + '...').trim()}}
            </p>
```

How do I correct this code to display in IE previous to IE9. I continue to get the following

> Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'trim'.

Answer (score 1):

Trim was not part of String till ECMAScript 5. IE9 is the first browser to support ECMAScript 5.

Though not recommended to modify the prototype of base classes,
if you wish you can add following lines of code for String.trim to work in all browsers.

```
  if (!String.prototype.trim) {
    String.prototype.trim = function() {
      return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    }
  }
```

Comment: where does this get added?

Comment: @user1920546 Anywhere before you use it. Preferably near the top of all your scripts